# In how many ways can $4$ different packages be distributed among $8$ people such that everyone gets $2$ packages or none?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I need some helps in terms of explanations for the answer for an exercise I’ve got in my lecture

The question is how many ways you can distribute $4$ different packages among $8$ people A, B,..., H, such that everyone gets $2$ packages or none.

The professor has given the answer, which is $\binom{8}{2}\binom{4}{2} = 28 \cdot 6$.

$\binom{4}{2}$, which is fine since we have to choose $2$ out of $4$ packages for distribution.

The part I can’t understand is why we have to choose specifically $2$ people but not $1$? The question does not imply that $2$ people should be chosen but instead, stated that, ”everyone.”

Thanks for your help in advance :):)

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, "everyone" means "each one".

Since there are $4$ packages, and each person gets either $2$ packages or none, it follows that exactly $2$ people will get packages, each of them getting $2$ packages.

To count the number of ways to distribute the packages . . .

First choose the $2$ people who will be given packages: $\binom{8}{2}$ choices.

Next choose $2$ packages to give to the first (order them arbitrarily) of the two chosen people:  $\binom{4}{2}$ choices.

Give the remaining two packages to the second person.

With those choices, the distribution is complete.

By the multiplication rule, the number of possible distributions is $\binom{8}{2}\binom{4}{2}$.

Comment: The second person might complain that the distribution is not complete because you did not give them the last two packages.  It is defined which two they will be. :)

Comment: Haha. I was assuming that was obvious, but to be sure (and complete!), I've edited in a sentence to address that point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) However, i still have a question. For example, if i give A 2 packages, then can i just leave the remaining 2 alone? Or i also have to distribute them for someone else, say B. Since we care about one gets 2 in 4 packages

Comment: @DinhHoang: The problem specified that 4 packages get distributed, so that should be interpreted as all 4 packages.

Comment: @DinhHoang: In my version of the count, I first select the $2$ people. Then I choose $2$ of the $4$ packages to give to the first person, and then give the other $2$ packages to the second person.

Comment: I got that point. Because i was thinking that after giving 2 packages for the first person, then i’m done there. That is why i came up with the question why we dont choose 1 person. Crystal clear! Thank so much 

Answer (score 0):

You need to pick $2$ people because you have $4$ packages, and each person can only receive $0$ or $2$ packages.

Comment: Do you mean that since we have 4 packages then we then have to choose 2 people? What if it is 5 or 6 packages? Are things gonna be different?

Comment: Yes.  And with $6$ packages we need $3$ people.  With $5$ packages we have a problem ...

Comment: What if i keep 6 packages , 8 people and change the questions to “everyone gets 3 packages or none”. I need 2 people right ? (i got it!). But what if “everyone gets 4 packages or none”?. I’m sorry if that does not make sense but usually i always think about variation of the question so that im sure that i understand

Comment: @user386182 yes, with 6 packages total and every getting exactly 3 or none, you need 2 people.  But with 6 packages and everyone getting 4 or none you have a problem again.

Answer (score 0):

Think like this:

Finally the four packages will be distributed, and since one person take two or none, there must be two lucky guys out of eight, so it's:

$$\binom{8}{2}.$$

And since we haven't decide that for each guy, which two types they receive? So let's choose for *the first guy*, and let the remainder for the second:

$$\binom{4}{2}.$$